# Fullcalendar: change the names for startParam / endParam keys

Tags: fullcalendar

I retrieve fullcalendar events from a database whose fields names for standard fullcalendar key names 'start' and 'end' are not 'start' and 'end'.

Is there a way to change those standard key names? It would be much simpler than manipulating the original data I receive from the database.

Comment: If you mean the parameters which are _sent_ to the server to tell the server the correct date range for which is should return events, then yes you can set https://fullcalendar.io/docs/startParam and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/endParam . But if you mean the fields in the events which you _output_ and send to fullCalendar, then no, you have to comply with the field names given at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object so that the calendar knows what each field represents when reading the event data.

Comment: What makes you feel that it's complicated to manipulate the original data you get from the database? Presumably you have some server-side code which reads the fields from the database and turns them into JSON? At that point it shouldn't be too difficult to just read your database date fields into object fields named "start" and "end" respectively.

Comment: No, there is nothing really difficult about changing the original field names in the database, albeit I should have preferred to keep them 'as is' for they are in a foreign language.. I am satisfied with your answers. Turn them into 'hard' answers and I shall vote them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the "start" and "end" parameters which are *sent* to the server to tell the server the correct date range for which is should return events, then yes you can set https://fullcalendar.io/docs/startParam and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/endParam .

But if you mean the fields in the events which you *output* and send to fullCalendar, then no, you have to comply with the field names given at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object so that the calendar knows what each field represents when reading the event data. Presumably you have some server-side code which reads the fields from the database and turns them into JSON? At that point it shouldn't be too difficult to just read your database date fields into object fields named "start" and "end" respectively. It's perhaps a bit of a chore, but you have to comply with the fullCalendar spec in this instance.

Comment: I have just followed your advice and generated an object whose field names comply with original fc key names. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with alias in the query and works perfect. In my case:

```
$sentenciaSQL = $conn->prepare("SELECT name as title, start_date as start, end_date as end, color as color FROM project_list");
```

where `conn` is the DB connection.